# ionic localStorage select

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage

I want to create setting page in my ionic app

**HTML :**

```
<select class="selectCountry">
    <option value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
</select>
```

**Controler.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngStorage'])

.controller('SettingsCtrl',function($scope, $localStorage){
// what to do to save and data from <select> & use if condition 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put `ng-model` on the `select` and trigger `onchange`  function

```
<select class="selectCountry" ng-model="selectCountry" ng-change="save()">
        <option value="fr">France</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
```

and in the controller

```
     angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngStorage'])

            .controller('SettingsCtrl',function($scope, $localStorage){
            // what to do to save and data from <select> & use if condition 
    $scope.save = function(){
    $localStorage.selectCountry= $scope.selectCountry; // set
alert($localStorage.selectCountry); // get
    }

        $localStorage.selectCountry = $localStorage.selectCountry; // get
            });
```

Check the docs for it [NgStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

i created this pen [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwyXxm)

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't work.
ReferenceError: Save is not defined

Comment: the problem  in  onchange="save()"

Comment: @HassanYorke it still have the save function with the capital `S` check the code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
.service('storage', function() {
      var myjsonObj = "nothing";//the object to hold our data
     return {
     setJson:function(name, item){
            window.localStorage.setItem( name, item );


     },
     getJson:function(name){
      return window.localStorage.getItem( name );
     }
     }
    })
```

if you wanna store and retrieve the variable.

```
storage.setJson("nameOfSetting", "theVariableYouWannaStore");
var theVariableYouStored = storage.getJson("nameOfSetting");
```